# Intent filter based on local file / Content

Tags: android, android-intent, local

I am trying to launch an Activity to catch the actions "share" , "send to" and "send multiples" on **local files** only.
That is, I want my app to be suggested as possible action when the user try to apply one of these three actions, for any kind of files, but for local actual files only.

I tried this:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I also declared same things for "action.SEND_MULTIPLE"  and "action.SENDTO" in separated intent-filters

But my app does not show up in the list of suggested app on share action from other apps...
If I replace android:scheme="content" by android:mimeType="*/*" then it works great, but for any kind of sharing, which is not what I want. I want this only for real local files...

thank you in advance !

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I am wondering the same.